# How to upload video from desktop use gem "ckeditor" in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video, upload, ckeditor

I use gem "ckeditor" for a textarea, but it just only upload image, i want to upload video from desktop/link online. How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can upload a video by using the "Link" option in Ckeditor.

See the image here:

[image: screenshot ckeditor upload]